# Can 'purview' and 'ambit' be used interchangeably?

Tags: grammar

Are there any specific rules for using those 2 words?
Like, in some situations, purview could be better, and in some others, ambit may seem good.

Comment: Go ahead if you mean the overlapping sense, not if not. The words have distinct meanings, especially in some contexts. "Like, in some situations, purview could be better, and in some others, ambit may seem good." The rule: check a dictionary first.

Comment: Yes, I did mean the overlapping sense, because, both words refer to 'range'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, I think "ambit" means "the scope" , whereas "purview" means "your scope" or "the scope you are responsible for."

Indeed, you could possibly say something like: "What is my purview? My purview is this particular ambit."  (!)

Purview kind of comes from words like "things you see, oversee", whereas ambit comes from words like "boundary, walk around, circle".

In short, ambit is more of a synonym of "scope."  Whereas purview is more of a synonym of "responsibility."

Hopefully this gives you a feel for the difference!